# what's the xpath to get href here?

Tags: python, html, xpath, html-parsing, lxml

I'm looking for the xpath to get href from

```
<a class="a-link-normal s-access-detail-page a-text-normal" title="Nikon Coolpix L330 - 20.2 MP Digital Camera with 26x zoom 35mm NIKKOR VR lens and FULL HD 720p (Black)" href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00HQDBLDO" rel="nofollow noreferrer"><h2 class="a-size-base s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal">Nikon Coolpix L330 - 20.2 MP Digital Camera with 26x zoom 35mm NIKKOR VR lens and FULL HD 720p (Black)</h2></a>
```

I tried following code:

```
url = "http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=digital+camera&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Adigital+camera"
page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
hrefs = tree.xpath('//*/a/@href')
for href in hrefs:
    if "keywords=digital+camera" in href:
        print href
```

Nothing is printed here.

I'm not sure if xpath can do this? Here's the link: http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=digital+camera

Comment: There are multiple ways to reach it by xpath. Since we don't see the complete HTML code (or a link to), we don't know how reliable the expression would be. Also, why the question is tagged with Python?

Comment: @alecxe the question is updated. thx

Comment: Thanks. What do you have as an input? I mean, the link title is something you can rely on?

Comment: yes. the link is the input. I want to get every href like http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00HQDBLDO.

Comment: @Tomalak I updated my code here. Pls advice.

Comment: For starters, you wrote `hmtl` instead of `html`.

Comment: It's corrected. pls advice

Answer (score 0):

try this.. But its always good if you try different things and then ask question if you are struck somewhere.

```
//a[@title='Nikon Coolpix L330 - 20.2 MP Digital Camera with 26x zoom 35mm NIKKOR VR lens and FULL HD 720p (Black)']
```

Comment: But there is one href in the post. Meanwhile try this
//a[@class='a-link-normal s-access-detail-page a-text-normal']/@href
It will get all hrefs of that class.

Comment: I need get all the href in that link ended with "keywords=digital+camera"

Comment: I tried. I returns href, but not the hrefs ended with "keywords=digital+camera". Any idea?

Comment: Try this...
//a[@class='a-link-normal s-access-detail-page a-text-normal'][contains(@href, 'keywords=digital+camera')]
I think this will do..

Comment: Is this a valid xpath, I got error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Yeah i checked that in xpath viewer.. or else u can add 'and' to that xpath expression.
//a[@class='a-link-normal s-access-detail-page a-text-normal' and contains(@href, 'keywords=digital+camera')]
I am getting 24 Matches.. I am using the link provided by you in the question.

Comment: What type of syntax error you are getting.. I checked it, it works for me..
If i use this expression then I am getting 179 Matches
//a[contains(@href, 'keywords=digital+camera')]..

Comment: It's wired. I didn't get anything here. Could you post your code here?

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is not "how to get the links by xpath", but "how to get the HTML code which contains the links that need to be retrieved by xpath".

The amazon page you see in the browser was constructed by it with a several additional asynchronous calls and by executing javascript. The HTML you get in the `page.text` is completely different from what you would see in the browser. It doesn't contain the desired links since `requests` is not a browser, at least, there is no javascript engine built-in.

The easiest solution here would be to automate a real browser with the help of [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=digital+camera')

for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href, "keywords=digital+camera")]'):
    print link.get_attribute('href')

driver.close()
```

Comment: I works well in mac or pc. But this soluntion couldn't work in ec2 instance since there's no graphic support. How could I get around this?

Comment: @c20ad4d76fe97759aa27a0c99bff67 phantomjs headless browser (`webdriver.PhantomJS`) or a virtual display (see `xvfb`) are usual solutions/workarounds.

Comment: Alternatively you could try spoofing the `User-Agent` header, maybe that's enough to fool Amazon into giving you the browser version of the page. The more sensible variant would be to think if you *really* need links that have the keyword in them, or if you can still solve your task without relying too much on Amazon's "browser-specific" href format.

Comment: @alecxe could you explain how do did with header? I don't quite understand. I tried using webdriver.PhantomJS( ), but it prints nothing. Not sure why.